# Environment variable causing git submodule to fail

Tags: linux, bash, git, git-submodules

When building a project with a simple script I ran into a strange failure when running trying to checkout the submodule (`git submodule update --init --recursive`)

I source a few environment variables from a script, `env.sh`

```sh
export jobs=`grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo`                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
export build_dir=...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
export source_dir=...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
export CC=...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
export CXX=...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
export FC=..
```

I then install my project with the following script, `build.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

source env.sh                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
function build() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        
  git clone <REPO_URL> .
  git submodule update --init --recursive  
  mkdir bld                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  cd bld                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  cmake ${source_dir}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=${CC} \                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=${CXX} \                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        -DCMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER=${FC} \                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${install_dir} \                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  make -j${jobs}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  make install                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
}
```

This script exits with the failure

```
error: pathspec '4' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

But when I run the same submodule command in my terminal it is successful

Answer (score 1):

I found that the problem was the `jobs` variable being set in `env.sh`. If this environment variable is set when calling `git submodule`, the value of that variable will be appended to the command line. `git submodule` then treats that argument as a path to the submodule, which doesn't exist.

So in any repo

`jobs=4 git submodule update --init --recursive`

will fail (assuming "4" isn't a valid path to a submodule in the repo).

I had this problem with `git` version 2.17.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04. It has been fixed in newer versions of git. I've been told this is fixed as of version 2.27.0 (shipped June 2020).

My solution was to update the name of the `jobs` variable to something less generic.